# Can any please let me how to pass a variable value to jar file using informatica java transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have created a mapping where i have imported the package (.jar) file in java transformation and this package will have set of queries which will access the oracle. To access the oracle driver in this package a variable has been declared(in that variable path has been assigned). So can any one please let me know how can i pass the path to this jar(Oracle installed path) file in java transformation, So that it will execute the query and produce the desired o/p.

Answer (score 0):

Have an expression transformation before the java transformation. Set the expression of one of the output ports of the expression transformation to be equal to a mapping parameter which is set to the value of the oracle path you want. You can then pass this value to the java transformation as an input port on the java transformation

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the solution, Will try the same and let you know.